# How does feature scaling improve convergence in gradient descent?

Tags: regression, gradient-descent

Based on answers online, it appears that feature scaling helps to (1) ensure balanced step sizes and (2) make the cost function more symmetrical.

Why would an imbalanced step size be an issue, since a large feature will generally have a larger derivative and vice versa - wouldn’t it just balance out? As it get closer, the cost decreases and it descends more slowly.

As for an symmetrical cost function, why would feature scaling makes it ‘rounder’?

Answer (score 2):

> As it get closer, the cost decreases and it descends more slowly.

Will you? That's the point why you have to rescale.

If you want to take a look, it has to do with the [conditioning number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) of the problem, and the problem is that if you just use naive SGD (so, no adaptive gradient/ momentum), a very ill-conditioned loss will have a very steep direction, and a very relaxed one, and feature scaling might be one of the causes, indeed:
$$
\begin{align}
\min L &= \min ([x_1, x_2][w_1, w_2]^T - Y)^2\\
&= \min ([x_1\cdot c , x_2][w_1/c, w_2]^T - Y)^2\\
\end{align}
$$
so you can freely scale any feature, and the minima will stay the same (loss-wise), however it's going to be much easier for first order optimizer to optimize the loss

Answer (score 1):

the issue is not the size of the gradient, but the size of the *change* in the gradient.
you want a small step size if the gradient changes dramatically (think of a ravine) and you want a large step size when the gradient stays the same.

the step size should depend on this curvature. The easiest example to look at is linear regression (with mean square error). the second derivative of the objective function wrt weights is $X^TX$, roughly speaking the covariance matrix. The error surface has elliptical level sets. the bigger the ratio between the minimum and maximum axes the slower will your convergence be: you want a large step size when going along the maximum axis (along a valley) and a small step size when going along the minimum axis.

Feature scaling will make the diagonals 1 (in linear regression above), so at least the curvature along each feature direction is the same, but curvature in combination of features will not be the same